# the program cannot run properly (dialog)

Tags: java, android, dialog

I followed the example of a Android book to draft a project.
However, there are some problems coming out:
When I touch a selection, the program will exit the program and returning a message "the application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again"
Would anyone can help me?

here is the source code:
    package com.example.ch07_dialogask;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity      //should be protected
implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{

TextView txv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Do you like Android phone?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_edit)
        .setTitle("Android survey")
        .setPositiveButton("Like",this)
        .setNegativeButton("Unlike",this)
        .setNeutralButton("No Comment",null)
        .show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
    if(id==DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE){
        txv.setText("You Like Android Phone!");
    }
    else if(id==DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE){
        txv.setText("You Dislike Android Phone.....");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the full error log, i suspect `txv` is null because you are using the wrong layout

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment yet. I don't have 50 reputation points yet.

Anyway, try putting the "new AlertDialog.Builder..." snippet on the onResume method of the activity.

I would bet that this is happening because the onCreate method isn't showing the layout yet. You can learn more about the Activity life cycle here: [Android Developer: Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). Also, try posting the Logcat with your questions. It helps a lot to learn what is going on.

Hope this helps you!

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     txv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
}

@Override
public void onStart(){ //Called when the activity is becoming visible to the user.
     super.onStart();
     new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage("Do you like Android phone?")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_edit)
    .setTitle("Android survey")
    .setPositiveButton("Like",this)
    .setNegativeButton("Unlike",this)
    .setNeutralButton("No Comment",null)
    .show();
}
```

Comment: 04-02 16:36:04.110: D/AndroidRuntime(319): Shutting down VM
04-02 16:36:04.110: W/dalvikvm(319): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-02 16:36:04.129: E/AndroidRuntime(319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 16:36:04.129: E/AndroidRuntime(319): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 16:36:04.129: E/AndroidRuntime(319):  at com.example.ch07_dialogask.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)
04-02 16:36:04.129: E/AndroidRuntime(319):at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)

Comment: 04-02 16:36:04.129: E/AndroidRuntime(319):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 16:36:04.129: E/AndroidRuntime(319):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-02 16:36:04.129: E/AndroidRuntime(319):at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-02 16:36:04.129: E/AndroidRuntime(319):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: 04-02 16:36:04.129: E/AndroidRuntime(319):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-02 16:36:04.129: E/AndroidRuntime(319):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-02 16:36:04.129: E/AndroidRuntime(319):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-02 16:36:04.129: E/AndroidRuntime(319): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Have you tried calling the AlertDialog.Builder on the onResume(...) callback of the Activity?

I have put an example on my answer.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Also, I just saw: you are passing "null" as the Listener on the setNeutralButton call. Try using "this" (as your activity is implementing the OnClickListener interface)